# SSH locale wrong

Tags: ssh, pam, putty, localization

I have a debian server with locales set to hu_HU.UTF-8, and if i log in trough console it works perfectly in hungarian. It also worked with ssh logins until i disabled PAM in the sshd config. Since then when i log in trough ssh the locales are set to POSIX.

I tried to comment the `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*` line in sshd_config but the problem still exits.
I'm connecting with Putty with UTF-8 character set.

So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### PuTTY doesn't set LANG

The locale you have set in PuTTY is completely decoupled from the environment variables on the system. To quote its documentation:

> Unfortunately, there is no satisfactory mechanism for PuTTY and the server to communicate this information, so it must usually be manually configured.

Before PuTTY changed the default character encoding to UTF-8, it was an extremely common scenario for the OS to have settings defaulting to a UTF-8 enabled locale (typically `en_US.UTF-8`) with PuTTY misinterpreting that by its own `ISO-8859-1:1998` default.

### PAM is more than just authentication

More than likely you've turned `UsePAM` to no, not realizing that this turns off far more than just PAM authentication. The operative words from the `sshd_config` manpage are:

> Enables the Pluggable Authentication Module interface.  If set to “yes” this will enable PAM authentication using ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication **in addition to PAM account and session module processing for all authentication types**.

Your console logins are still invoking PAM modules associated with the `account` and `session` facilities, but your SSH logins are no longer doing so. I recommend that you re-enable PAM. At this point you can disable `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` if your goal is to require key based authentication. (which has always bypassed PAM's `auth` facility)

Comment: I was having the problem that `/etc/default/locale` wasn't taking effect on ssh login, this was resolved by changing `UsePAM no` to `UsePAM yes`. Thank you!